# PHP tmp dir randomly causing upload issues on cpanel server

Tags: php, cpanel

I've just run into a strange issue with the `upload_tmp_dir`. Everything has been working fine for months for file uploads, but today uploads stopped working and the output of `$_FILES` shows tmp_name as being empty and error 6 - meaning there is no tmp directory set.

Very strange how it just happened, this is on a CPanel server, so I manually set the `upload_tmp_dir` to `/home/uploadtmp` and `chmod` to 775 and then added this to `php.ini`.

I checked the loaded php.ini file as:

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.ini
```

But `phpinfo()` still says the upload tmp dir is not set? It is set, I've already restarted apache and it still causing issues.

Any idea on why this is happening all of a sudden?

Comment: Also, check your CPanel change log. `;-)`

Comment: Also, SO may not be the best place to ask; why not raise a support ticket with CPanel or [check their support / dev forums](https://forums.cpanel.net/)?

Comment: in `phpinfo()` follow the `Loaded .ini file` (or whatever it's called) - that's your actual ini. It's also possible that other services are needing restarting, e.g. if you have PHP-FPM installed, you'll have to restart that as well